# numerical recipies ran3 generates negative numbers

Tags: random, fortran

I am using numerical recipes scheme to generate random numbers (`ran3`, page 7 [in this PDF file](http://www.aip.de/groups/soe/local/numres/bookfpdf/f7-1.pdf)). I didn't notice anything strange but this time, I got a negative numbers at the "warm up" stage which are larger than `MBIG`. The code look as if this shouldn't happen. I can easily fix this with changing the if statement to be a while statement at the line that says `if(mk.lt.MZ)mk=mk+MBIG` but I want to know what are the consequences.

Edit:here is the function

```
      FUNCTION ran3a(idum) 
      INTEGER idum
      INTEGER MBIG,MSEED,MZ 
C     REAL MBIG,MSEED,MZ
      REAL ran3a,FAC
      PARAMETER (MBIG=1000000000,MSEED=161803398,MZ=0,FAC=1./MBIG)  
C     PARAMETER (MBIG=4000000.,MSEED=1618033.,MZ=0.,FAC=1./MBIG) 
      INTEGER i,iff,ii,inext,inextp,k
      INTEGER mj,mk,ma(55)  
C     REAL mj,mk,ma(55) 
      SAVE iff,inext,inextp,ma
      DATA iff /0/
      if(idum.lt.0.or.iff.eq.0)then
        iff=1
        mj=MSEED-iabs(idum) 
        mj=mod(mj,MBIG) 
        ma(55)=mj
        mk=1
        do 11 i=1,54
          ii=mod(21*i,55) 
          ma(ii)=mk
          mk=mj-mk
          if(mk.lt.MZ)mk=mk+MBIG
          mj=ma(ii)  
11      continue
        do 13 k=1,4
          do 12 i=1,55
            ma(i)=ma(i)-ma(1+mod(i+30,55)) 
            if(ma(i).lt.MZ)ma(i)=ma(i)+MBIG 
12        continue 
13      continue 
        inext=0
        inextp=31
        idum=1
      endif
      inext=inext+1
      if(inext.eq.56)inext=1
      inextp=inextp+1
      if(inextp.eq.56)inextp=1
      mj=ma(inext)-ma(inextp) 
      if(mj.lt.MZ)mj=mj+MBIG
      ma(inext)=mj
      ran3a=mj*FAC
      return
      END
```

Comment: I have never seen a negative number using ran3. Can you post your code?

Comment: Sorry for the long time, I've uploaded the code.

Comment: Thats the code from the book. We need your code.

Comment: almost certainly you are exceeding the max value that can be stored in a default integer.  Try declaring all your integers *8 or kind=8..  your mbig fits in 32 bits, the likely default, but its cutting close..

Comment: @george, as it stands, `huge(mbig)` gives me 2147483647 (a difference of 1147483647). Using `integer*8` (which is not a good idea anyway) gives me a max number of 9223372036854775807. The default integer is good enough.

Comment: @VladimirF This is my code. This is why I didn't post it here.

Comment: @george I doubled MBIG and this fixed this. The starting value was a big number and this is probably the problem (idum changes between simulations)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was getting Seg Faults (using gfortran 4.8) because the function was trying to change the input value `idum` from the negative number to 1. There is no reason for that line (nor anything with `iff`), so I deleted it and printed out the array `ma` at several different places and found no negative numbers in the array.

One possibility, though, is if `iabs(idum)` is larger than `MSEED`, you might have a problem with the line `mj=MSEED - iabs(idum)`. You should protect from this by using `mj=abs(MSEED-abs(idum))` like the book has written.

Answer (score -3):

Had a look at the pdf.  What you need to do is

1) Seed it: value = ran3(-1)

2) Use it:  value = ran3(0)

Comment: That's not what he's asking. He's finding that his array `ma` has negative numbers and wants to know what happens if he changes the code to avoid those negative numbers.