# I need help to find out what this algorithm does

Tags: c, algorithm, math, random

I was given a .C file which i don't know what it does and I'm supposed to find out... after running it i think it is some sort of random number generator but i totally have no idea... i was wandering if anyone one of you has ever seen the algorithm implemented in the *rf* function:

```
/* ===========================================HEADERS=============================================== */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

/* ============================================INIRAN================================================ */
typedef struct {
    int seme;
} iniran;

/* ==============================================RF================================================== */
float rf(int *idum){

    static int iff=0;
    static int inext, inextp, ma[55];
    int mj, mk;
    int i, k, ii;
    float ret_val;

    if (*idum<0 || iff==0) {
        iff=1;
        mj=161803398 - abs(*idum);
        mj %= 1000000000;
        ma[54]=mj;
        mk=1;

        for (i=1; i<=54; ++i){
           ii=(i*21)%55;
           ma[ii-1]=mk;
           mk=mj-mk;
           if (mk<0) {
               mk += 1000000000;
           }
           mj= ma[ii-1];
        }

    for(k=1; k<=4; ++k) {
        for(i=1; i<=55; ++i){
        ma[i-1] -= ma[(i+30)%55];
            if (ma[i-1]<0){
                ma[i-1] += 1000000000;
            }
        }
    }

    inext=0;
    inextp=31;
    *idum=1;
    }

    ++inext;
    if (inext==56){
        inext=1;
    }
    ++inextp;
    if (inextp==56){
        inextp=1;
    }
    mj=ma[inext-1]-ma[inextp-1];
    if (mj<0){
        mj += 1000000000;
    }
    ma[inext-1]=mj;
    ret_val=mj*1.0000000000000001e-9;
    return ret_val;
}

/* ============================================MAIN================================================ */
int main(void){

/* Variable declaration */
int Np=10000;
int jp1, jp2, jp3, jp4, jp5;

/* Rinominate struct */
iniran iniran1;
iniran1.seme=7593; 

jp1=1+floorf(Np*rf(&iniran1.seme));
jp2=1+floorf(Np*rf(&iniran1.seme));
jp3=1+floorf(Np*rf(&iniran1.seme));
jp4=1+floorf(Np*rf(&iniran1.seme));
jp5=1+floorf(Np*rf(&iniran1.seme));

printf("jp1 = %d, jp2 = %d, jp3 = %d, jp4 = %d, jp5 = %d \n", jp1, jp2, jp3, jp4, jp5);

return 0;
}
```

In order to run it you must type `gcc test.c -lm` in the terminal. I know there's little information but maybe you have seen this kind of algorithm before and you might help me to understand what it is going on... any suggestion is welcome

Comment: debug in your compiler ... Your compiler itself will tell you what this code does.

Comment: @MukitChowdhury: It is clear he tried to run it, and guess what, he had seen random numbers... If I happened to meet the same, neither I would have been able to figure it out without gathering help from outside. A bit strange, but totally OK question, I seriously wonder what's wrong with those who downvoted this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just searching for the code on Google yields e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16757154/numerical-recipies-ran3-generates-negative-numbers) which uses similiar variable names and constants (note e.g. 161803398 or the array `ma` with 55 elements). In fact (my Fortran is kinda rusty) it appears to be the exact same algorithm -- and that question is about a random number generator.

Some [more research](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23688168/is-161803398-a-special-number-inside-of-math-random) suggests that this is a C implementation of Knuth's [subtractive](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Subtractive_generator) random number generator algorithm.

Comment: Wow!! that's what i wanted to hear... this code must come from the same source you found!!! thanks!!!